# When people go to heaven, does their spelling improve?

Tags: protestantism, heaven, evangelicalism

Note: by Heaven I mean the "temporary state before the resurrection".

In other words, do people keep their virtues, morals, skills, faults, wickedness when they go to heaven?

Or do they become better and get rid of all (or part) of their faults and wickedness?

And what about their virtues. Are they enhanced beyond what they normally were when living?

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks for contributing. If you haven't done so please take [the tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out more about how this site works. I understand that asking about spelling was probably intended to be a joke. However it would be better to ask about real virtues and abilities, and maybe edit out the reference to spelling? Nobody knows anything about people's ability to spell, or need to spell, in heaven.

Comment: Can you say what you mean by 'heaven' - is this a temporary state before the resurrection, or life in a bodily resurrected state?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, the spelling phrasing is to put the question in a lighter way. As you see the real question is if we remain exactly the same ones with all good and bad in us, or if we are somehow "changed".

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Your comment made me think. Do those two heavens have different names or the same one? Just thinking people have only been to te first one so far.

Comment: Great question! Actually made me laugh. Please reopen it and lets have some answers. I am mindful of 1 Cor. 13:8 "as for knowledge, it shall vanish away."

Comment: @JoeDiNottra re 'heaven', that's a big debate! Some say people sleep until the resurrection, some say they go to God's presence and then there is a resurrection, some say they resurrect immediately. 'Heaven' can mean various things, but general or universal resurrection is the term for the bodily resurrection of everyone.

Comment: @Mick Yes, it's a shame it was closed. It's an honest question and I still would like to know. If it can be improved in any way, I'm all for it.